# How to modify List<> between two classes in unity?

Tags: c#, list, oop, unity-game-engine

In unity I'm making a program that allows you to click on a cube and select spheres that represent the vertices as shown below:

[image: Cube with vertices]

Once theses spheres are selected they are to be added to the list `selectedSpheres` of type `GameObject`.

I've created two class files - `Cube.cs` and `Vertex.cs`. `Vertex` inherits from `Cube` which inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. In Cube I have a member list that stores the selected spheres.

I have defined a function `addToSelected()` which adds the input to the `selectedSpheres` list. The print statement inside the function prints off true every single time. But the print statement in the `Update()` function prints an Argument out of range error as shown below while the `addToSelected()` has shown that it has worked 8 times:

[image: Error]

The `addToSelected()` function is called from the `OnMouseDown()` function inside the `Vertex` class. The code for both classes is shown below:

**Cube.cs**

```
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {

    bool isSelected = false;
    GameObject[] Spheres;
    List<GameObject> selectedSpheres = new List<GameObject>();

    public void addToSelected(GameObject obj) {
        selectedSpheres.Add(obj);
        print(selectedSpheres.Contains(obj));
    }

    public void removeSelected(GameObject obj) {
        selectedSpheres.Remove(obj);
    }

    public void clearSelected() {
        selectedSpheres.Clear();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            print(selectedSpheres[0]);
        }
    }
 }
```

**Vertex.cs**

```
public class Vertex : Cube {

    void OnMouseDown() {
        // this object was clicked - do something
        Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        if (rend.material.color != Color.red) {
            rend.material.color = Color.red; // #d96459
            addToSelected(this.gameObject);

        } else {
            rend.material.color = Color.white;
            removeSelected(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Vertex inherits form Cube and Cube has the Update function

```
void Update() {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        print(selectedSpheres[0]);
    }
}
```

the statement `print(selectedSpheres[0]);` is executed inside of all objects that inherit from Cube everytime you press the space key. In some (or most) instances of Vertex `selectedSpheres` is empty, which is why you get an argument out of range error. Also, you have defined a `selectedSpheres` list for every instance of Cube (and therefore Vertex). So you have 9 instances of `selectedSpheres` in your sample scene. The shortest way to  fix this would be to declare `selectedSpheres` as static. Then, you would have only one list for all instances of Cube/Vertex.

So go ahead and try:

```
static List<GameObject> selectedSpheres = new List<GameObject>();
```

Comment: That works, thanks. However I'm curious why making it private doesn't work? If it was private then Vertex shouldn't inherit `selectedSpheres` from Cube, so I would think it would work.

Comment: Wait never mind, if i made `selectedSpheres` private and did an override on the `Update` function then it _should_ work

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. `Vertex` shouldn't inherit from `Cube` since a vertex is not a cube.
2. This inheritance is creating a number of lists: every vertex has its own list `selectedSpheres` since it inherits the list from `Cube`. I hope you realise that the way it is now, each vertex is inserting itself inside its own list, so each `selectedSpheres` would always have 0 or 1 elements.
3. `addToSelect` (and probably other methods) shouldn't be *public*, since you don't want to call it from other classes. It can't be *private* as your comment says because then the inherited class couldn't use it; it has to be ***protected***, if you insist with the inheritance.
4. Printing `selectedSpheres[0]` is bad because in your case the list may be empty and that would generate the argument out of range exception you were getting.

I'd say all these problems are caused by the inheritance: *cubes **have** vertices* and not *vertices are cubes*. You should have a list of vertices in the cube, a boolean to tell if the vertex is selected and a method in the cube to go over the vertices list and return the ones that are selected (that would be the equivalent of `Cube`'s `selectedSpheres`).

You could have an abstract class or an interface to represent the stuff that both classes has in common, like `isSelected` or maybe `addToSelect` so both classes would implement/inherit from it, but again, not make `Vertex` inherit from `Cube`.

Comment: I totally agree with point 1. I honestly did it that way because I'm new to OOP and I figured it would work but it's definitely not a clean solution. I've heard of abstract classes and interfaces vaguely before but I don't know how to use them and until now when to use them. Could you point me in the right direction on how to either define an interface and then implement it, or "inherit" (not sure if that's the right term) from an abstract class?

Comment: I think you should look for a OOP tutorial, a simple one would give you a high level understanding of these things and the time you'd spend would be paid off because you'd be able to code much quicker and have much less problems. Polymorphism and Access Modifiers are one of the first things to be learned, I think. Then you'll be able to do this by yourself, very easily.